# Displaying from models to a template page in django

Tags: python, django

I want to display the data of models to my template file but it just can't work it doesn't even show an error message, even when I pass a *QuerySet* of message objects as context to the render function.

**App Name is CD**

Here my code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.

def index(requets):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    context =  {'tasks': tasks}

    return render(requets, 'CD/home.html', context)
```

my template **home.html**

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    <h1>{{task.texts}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you have a mistype here `{{task.texts}}`, it should be `{{ task.text }}`

Answer (score -1):

you should use text instead of texts in template

use this :

```
        {% for task in tasks %}
        <h1>{{task.text}}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).